# app icon on click event from home screen

Tags: android

Each time my app icon from home screen is clicked, I want the app to start my `FirstActivity.java`. The problem now is, say I have navigated through my app and is in the `ThirdActivity.java` and I have clicked the home `Button` and go to check out my other apps. Again when I click the app icon in home screen, my `Application` starts from `ThirdActivity.java`. I want it to start from `FirstActivity.java`.

I have used `clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` in manifest for my `FirstActivity.java` and also checked using `android:finishOnTaskLaunch ="true"` in all my other activities but the problem is still there. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can implement by two ways: 1)either finish your current activity whenever your second and third activity is paused(not recommended). 2)You can use Application class, where whenever your app starts launch your firstactivity.

Comment: @himanshu munjal Thank You! But I cant just finish my activity everytime I pause. The user has the option of selecting the app again from the background apps section (task manager section). If he/she does so, i want it to start from where he/she has left. only if they click the app icon should the app start from start. Can u explain the second answer(ou can use Application class, where whenever your app starts launch your firstactivity)?

Comment: Yup. in this case second option is better. create a class which extends Application and in its on create you can start your first activity as this on create will always call whenever application is restarted.

Comment: @himanshu munjal Can u explain this using a sample code? public class Test extends Application{ oncreate(){//what should we write here}............ Also <activity
            android:name=."FirstActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> what change should i bring to my manifest.

Comment: You also have to try by removing launcher filter, I am not sure about it. just try both ways.

Comment: See the answer given by me and then code accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I have to do was declare android:launchMode="singleTask" in manifest for my FirstActivity.java "only". By doing this, every time user selects the app by clicking the app icon in the home screen, app will start with FirstActivity.java

Say the user has navigated through my app and is in the ThirdActivity.java and clicked the home Button. The user has the option of selecting the app again from the background apps section (task manager section). If he/she does so, it will start from where he/she has left (ThirdActivity.java). Only if they click the app icon will the app start from FirstActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

you need to finish you current activity at the time when you are launching intent for new activity, there is a method to do that `finish();`

Comment: Thank You! But I cant just finish my activity everytime I pause. The user has the option of selecting the app again from the background apps section (task manager section). If he/she does so, i want it to start from where he/she has left. only if they click the app icon should the app start from start.

Answer (score 0):

In your oncreate you just have to start your activity using Intent

In manifest you have to provide name attribute to application tag

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 

       android:name=".class name which extends Application"

        >
```

Here you can see details on how to use application class:
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136

Comment: Sorry!! The solution is not working for me... I have created an application class as shown in the example and called it in my FirstActivity.java... Gave application name in manifest as shown by you.. but the problem still exist..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in `onPause()` of the second third activity but you have to take care of if `onPause()` is called because of clicking home button or by any other mean, Code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AnyActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `moveTaskToBack(true)` when you click on the homebutton and start the activity you want to.

Comment: Thank You. I have already found a solution for this. I will also try this and get back to you..

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved the issue by adding all three tags android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
android:finishOnTaskLaunch ="true" 
in manifest splash screen activity may be helped some one:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:finishOnTaskLaunch ="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeForAppCompact">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```